# Is there a ranking metric based on percentages that favors larger magnitudes?

Tags: statistics, analysis, ranking, information-retrieval

I have two groups, "in" and "out," and item categories that can be split up among the groups. For example, I can have item category A that is 99% "in" and 1% "out," and item B that is 98% "in" and 2% "out."

For each of these items, I actually have the counts that are in/out. For example, A could have 99 items in and 1 item out, and B could have 196 items that are in and 4 that are out.

I would like to rank these items based on the percentage that are "in," but I would also like to give some priority to items that have larger overall populations. This is because I would like to focus on items that are very relevant to the "in" group, but still have a large number of items in the "out" group that I could pursue.

Is there some kind of score that could do this?

Comment: [Cross-post](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/225975/is-there-a-ranking-metric-based-on-percentages-that-favors-larger-magnitudes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ultimately ended up using bayesian averaging, which was recommended in [this post.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/225975/is-there-a-ranking-metric-based-on-percentages-that-favors-larger-magnitudes) The technique is briefly described in [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_average) and more thoroughly described in [this post by Evan miller](http://www.evanmiller.org/bayesian-average-ratings.html) and [this post by Paul Masurel](http://fulmicoton.com/posts/bayesian_rating).

In bayesian averaging, "prior values" are used to influence the numerator and denominator towards the expected values. Essentially, the expected numerator and expected denominator are added to the actual numerator and denominator. In the case where the numerator and denominator are small, the prior values have a larger impact because they represent a larger proportion of the new numerator/denominator. As the numerators and denominators grow in magnitude, the bayesian average starts to approach the actual average due to increased confidence.

In my case, the prior value for the average was fairly low, which biased averages with small denominators downward.

Answer (score 1):

I'd be tempted to use a probabilistic rank — the probability that an item category is from the group given the actual numbers for that category. This requires making some assumptions about the data set, including why a category may have any out-of-group items. You might take a look at the [binomial test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_test) or the [Mann-Whitney U test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mann%E2%80%93Whitney_U_test) for a start. You might also look at some other kinds of [nonparametric statistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonparametric_statistics).

Comment: Thanks! I should clarify some additional numbers I have. For a category, I know the number that are in and out. I also know the total number that are in across all categories, as well as the total number that are out across all categories. I'll take a look at the links you provided and see if they work.

Comment: @neelshiv - I figured you had all that info. What you haven't indicated is whether or not you have probability distributions to explain the data. That's why I suggest the use of nonparametric methods, since these require fewer assumptions (at the expense of discriminating power, of course; there's no free lunch here). If you are willing to assume a particular distribution, you can use an appropriate parametric test scores for your ranking.

Comment: gotcha. Let me read up on those subjects and try a few things, and I'll report back in a day or so.

Comment: I ultimately ended up using a bayesian average, which seems to be somewhat related.